# MariaDB won't start with CIFS share as datadir

Tags: mysql, cifs, mariadb-10.4

I have a rather peculiar problem with MariaDB on Ubuntu Server 18.04 when using a CIFS share as its datadir.

The setup is a fileserver hosted at 192.168.4.10 and my MariaDB database server at 192.168.4.8. I now want to store the "hot data" of the database server on my fileserver. For this purpose I created a SMB/CIFS share on my fileserver which the database server is supposed to use to store its data (by default located in `/var/lib/mysql`) on the fileserver (the task has been given to use by our lecturer so please no discussions if this setup makes sense for a production database).

I use AutoFS to mount the CIFS share. Configs look like this

**/etc/auto.master**

```
[...]
/var/autofs/net        /etc/auto.db-slave --timeout 300 --mode 0777
```

**/etc/auto.db-slave**

```
db-slave        -fstype=cifs,username=smbmysql,password=***,rw,vers=3.0,uid=mysql,gid=mysql,forceuid,forcegid,dir_mode=0777,file_mode=0777,hard,intr,noperm        ://192.168.4.10/db_slave
```

I also created a (soft) symlink from `/var/lib/mysql -> /var/autofs/net/db-slave`

The share works just fine, I can `cd` to the folder, and when I switch to the mysql user with `sudo -su mysql` I can also edit/create/remove files and directories and the changes are correctly reflected on my fileserver.

However when I try to start the MariaDB service again with `sudo systemctl start mariadb` it fails to start and the logfile looks like this:

```
Dec 11 11:01:12 vmpsateam04-08 mysqld[1291]: 2019-12-11 11:01:12 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 10.4.10-MariaDB-1:10.4.10+maria~bionic-log) starting as process 1291 ...
Dec 11 11:01:12 vmpsateam04-08 mysqld[1291]: 2019-12-11 11:01:12 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
Dec 11 11:01:12 vmpsateam04-08 mysqld[1291]: 2019-12-11 11:01:12 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
Dec 11 11:01:12 vmpsateam04-08 mysqld[1291]: 2019-12-11 11:01:12 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
Dec 11 11:01:12 vmpsateam04-08 mysqld[1291]: 2019-12-11 11:01:12 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
Dec 11 11:01:12 vmpsateam04-08 mysqld[1291]: 2019-12-11 11:01:12 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
Dec 11 11:01:12 vmpsateam04-08 mysqld[1291]: 2019-12-11 11:01:12 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
Dec 11 11:01:12 vmpsateam04-08 mysqld[1291]: 2019-12-11 11:01:12 0 [Note] mysqld: O_TMPFILE is not supported on /tmp (disabling future attempts)
Dec 11 11:01:12 vmpsateam04-08 mysqld[1291]: 2019-12-11 11:01:12 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 256M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
Dec 11 11:01:12 vmpsateam04-08 mysqld[1291]: 2019-12-11 11:01:12 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
Dec 11 11:01:12 vmpsateam04-08 mysqld[1291]: 2019-12-11 11:01:12 0 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. See the man page of setpriority().
Dec 11 11:01:12 vmpsateam04-08 mysqld[1291]: 2019-12-11 11:01:12 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Cannot read first page of './ibdata1' I/O error
Dec 11 11:01:12 vmpsateam04-08 mysqld[1291]: 2019-12-11 11:01:12 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Plugin initialization aborted with error I/O error
Dec 11 11:01:12 vmpsateam04-08 mysqld[1291]: 2019-12-11 11:01:12 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
Dec 11 11:01:12 vmpsateam04-08 mysqld[1291]: 2019-12-11 11:01:12 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
Dec 11 11:01:12 vmpsateam04-08 mysqld[1291]: 2019-12-11 11:01:12 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
Dec 11 11:01:12 vmpsateam04-08 mysqld[1291]: 2019-12-11 11:01:12 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
Dec 11 11:01:12 vmpsateam04-08 mysqld[1291]: 2019-12-11 11:01:12 0 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
Dec 11 11:01:12 vmpsateam04-08 mysqld[1291]: 2019-12-11 11:01:12 0 [ERROR] Aborting
```

As you can see the problem seems to be that the InnoDB engine cannot read `./ibdata1`. The file is fine however, since when I disable the share and copy all the files back from my fileserver to `/var/lib/mysql` the MariaDB service starts just fine.

As you can see I tried all the access mask parameters I could find in my AutoFS config (that's why there's all those mode, uid, gid, etc. params) but so far to no avail.

EDIT3: I did what @danblack suggested and ran `strace -fe trace=%desc -o /tmp/mysqld.strace /usr/sbin/mysqld` as the mysql user. You can find the full file on [WeTransfer](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/aaff66c1cef515b21997ade9c0029e0f20191211195807/2d4453), hopefully someone is able to make sense of it all.

The critical piece of the trace is:

```
1625  openat(AT_FDCWD, "./ibdata1", O_RDWR|O_CLOEXEC) = 7
1625  fcntl(7, F_SETFL, O_RDONLY|O_DIRECT) = 0
1625  fcntl(7, F_SETLK, {l_type=F_WRLCK, l_whence=SEEK_SET, l_start=0, l_len=0}) = 0
1625  fstat(7, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0777, st_size=79691776, ...}) = 0
1625  pread64(7, 0x56003fa78000, 65536, 0) = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
```

Comment: after `su` to `mysql`, I'd try `strace -fe trace=file -o /tmp/mysqld.strace /usr/sbin/mysqld` and see which system call related to ibdata1 occurs before the error is produced.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I did that and edited my original post to cover the result.

Comment: Apologies, file was insufficient. The openat call at the end was successful and the error relates to a read of the first page. `trace=%desc` includes read/write/mmap calls.

Comment: Done, edited the link in the original post, skimming through it I didn't see anything but maybe you can make sense of it :)

Comment: 7 is the file descriptor and the following operations are on it. Included in your questions to avoid the WeTransfer conditions. I'm not sure of the EINVAL reason. I'd suggest increasing the `rsize` to 64k in the [cifs mount options](https://linux.die.net/man/8/mount.cifs) and looking in the CIFS server logs, perhaps with enhanced logging.